# Модальное окно jQuery в iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!
Есть страничка на которой на которой набор ссылок, при клике на ссылку открывается всплывающее окно на `jQuery`. Если эту страничку засунуть на другой сайт в `iframe`, то всплывающее окно обрезается границами фрейма. 
Можно сделать так чтобы это окно открывалось как будто это вовсе не фрейм.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, если только не перенести его в родитель, а перенести его можно, только если iframe находится на том же домене (либо под домене).

**UPD** (никогда не делайте так):

- http://jsfiddle.net/NvP2g/show/
- http://jsfiddle.net/YnzZp/ — iframe
- http://jsfiddle.net/NvP2g/ — родитель

Comment: Если на одном и том же, то тогда как сделать? Просто страницы написаны разными людьми, одна на php, другая java - никто ничего переписывать и копаться в чужом не хочет, а вставка одного в другое нужна.

Comment: обновил комент.